# Calculating column values based on positive/negative values of another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I am typing randomly positive and negative values in column A in Excel sheet then I want when I type any positive value in column A then counting should start in column B and if I type any negative value then it should start its separate counting in column C.

For example I have attached a snapshot of an Excel sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In B2:

```
=IF(A2<0,"",COUNTIF(A$2:A2,">=0"))
```

In C2:

```
=IF(A2<0,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,"<0"),"")
```

Copy these down the columns for as many rows as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula for cell B2 and drag it for all the B column

```
=if(A2>0, max(B1$:B1)+1, "")
```

For the C column, you'll have to change the > to < and the same formula should work.

Comment: What if the value entered in column A is 0?